# Make country default in form as "United States"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make the default value for the country input in a form to be "United States". I am using the simple form gem and country select gem.

In the simple form initializer, I set this default

```
  config.country_priority = [ "United States" ]
```

Which makes the topmost value correct as United States, but the default value is 'Uganda'.

In the _form view, I did the following:

```
<%= f.input :country, :default => [ 'United States' ] %>
```

I restarted Rails and it still defaulted to Uganda.

I also tried the following:

```
<%= f.input :country, :default => 'United States' %>
```

and

```
<%= f.input :country, :selected => 'United States' %>
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the gem -- too much complexity. I just created a constant COUNTRIES and used that instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
<%= form.country_select :country, ["United States"] %>
```

Comment: I still get 'Uganda' as the default. This is really baffling. I searched all the files for 'Uganda' and it did not come up anywhere.

Comment: However, it does make the United States the first selection in the list.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this with gem 'country_select' in simple-form. It's worked for me.

```
= f.input :country,  priority: [ "Brazil" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I just recently did this and thought I'd share to help others. I'm using Rails 4.2.0, country_select (2.1.1), and simple_form (3.1.0). This worked for me:

`<%= f.input :country, selected: 'US' %>`

If you want to prevent the user from changing the selection, use `:disabled` like so:

`<%= f.input :country, selected: 'US', disabled: true %>`

Just to clarify the `:priority` option in the other answers, that only gives that country higher priority (i.e. it will place the country at the top of the dropdown list), it doesn't actually select that country. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Am using this and it works. Using formtastic gem, add below line.

```
          <% f.input :address_country, :as => :country, :priority_countries => ["United States", "United Kingdom","Australia", "New Zealand"] %>
```

Note: The countries inside the array are the priority countries which are displayed first before the entire global countries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the country code instead of the country name:

```
<%= form.country_select :country, ["US"] %>
```

Comment: you need to use the country code instead of country name.

Answer (score -1):

You should only have to do:

```
<%= f.country_select("user", "country_name", [ "United States" ]) %>
```

Where `user` is the name of the [model you are using](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#example).

Comment: When I tried that I got the error message 'undefined method `merge' for ["United States"]:Array'

Answer (score -1):

I've just encountered this problem. It's working on 3fb63542c085148bcea73198037d37f15c6154d7 github revision of https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select :

```
<%= f.country_select :country, selected: 'US' %>
```

Comment: US will be selected always